# JavaScript: show an image resulting from user's choice(insert in prompt) + computer's choice

Tags: javascript, image, prompt, console.log

I have this code:

```js
         /*
   *
   * Game Part 1: Getting the user's choice and the computer's randomly choice 
   *
   */
   var userChoice = prompt("What's your nature element?");
   var computerChoice = Math.random();
   // get computer's randomly choice by "if" conditioning
   if(computerChoice <= 0.25)
   {
    computerChoice = "water";
   }
   else if(computerChoice <= 0.50)
   {
    computerChoice = "fire";
   }
   else if(computerChoice <= 0.75)
   {
    computerChoice = "air";
   }
   else
   {
    computerChoice = "earth";
   }

   console.log("Computer's choosen element: " + computerChoice);

   // This function will show the elements combination image
   function show_combination_image(src) {
       var img = document.createElement("img");
       img.src = src;

       // This line will just add it to the <body> tag
       document.body.appendChild(img);
   }

   /*
   *
   * Game Part 2: Combining user's choice with computer's choice and returning the result
   *
   */

   var combine = function(element1, element2)
   {
    
    // if the choosen elements are the same
    if(element1 === element2)
   {
    return "It seems that your element and computer's element are the same. You need to make a combination, therefore please insert a different element.";
   }
    
    // else if user chooses the "water" element
    else if(element1 === "water")
    {
     if(element2 === "fire")
     {
      show_combination_image("img/water+fire.jpg");
     }
     else if(element2 === "air")
     {
      show_combination_image("img/water+air.jpg");
     }
     else (element2 === "earth")
     {
      show_combination_image("img/water+earth.jpg");
     }
    }
    
    // else if user chooses the "fire" element
    else if(element1 === "fire")
    {
     if(element2 === "water")
     {
      show_combination_image("img/water+fire.jpg");
     }
     else if(element2 === "air")
     {
      show_combination_image("img/fire+air.jpg");
     }
     else
     {
      show_combination_image("img/fire+earth.jpg");
     }
    }
    
    // else if user chooses the "air" element
    else if(element1 === "air")
    {
     if(element2 === "water")
     {
      show_combination_image("img/water+air.jpg");
     }
     else if(element2 ==="fire")
     {
      show_combination_image("img/fire+air.jpg");
     }
     else
     {
      show_combination_image("img/air+earth.jpg");
     }
    }
    
    // else if user chooses the "earth" element
    else if(element1 === "earth")
    {
     if(element2 === "water")
     {
      show_combination_image("img/water+earth.jpg");
     }
     else if(element2 === "fire")
     {
      show_combination_image("img/fire+earth.jpg");
     }
     else
     {
      show_combination_image("img/air+earth.jpg");
     }
    }
   } 

   /*
   *
   * Game Part 3: Getting the user's element and the computer's randomly element and show the combination image
   *
   */

   combine(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

I get the prompt alert box and after I insert some element, like: water, fire, earth or air, I'm getting just blank page. 
I want to show an image resulting from the combination of my chosen element and computer's chosen element.

Can you please tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Take a close look at the first `if` statement in your "combine" function. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I just corrected the first if with this: `// if the choosen elements are the same
    if(element1 === element2)
    {
     return "It seems that your element and computer's element are the same. You need to make a combination, therefore please insert a different element.";
    }`

Comment: But it's still blank...

Comment: If I'm inserting the "fire" element in the prompt, I get this error in console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`

Comment: That means your code is running before there's a `<body>` in the DOM. Move your `<script>` to inside the `<body>` at the very end (right before `</body>`).

Comment: hahaaaaaaaa, it worked ! thank you, Pointy, for your time ! I appreciate !